# Sitecore Velocity How to build the URL of the Item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

I m using the following code to visualize different information in the email message.

```
   this.velocityContext.Put("args", args);
            this.velocityContext.Put("item", args.DataItem); 
            this.velocityContext.Put("processor", args.ProcessorItem);
            this.velocityContext.Put("user", Context.User); 
            this.velocityContext.Put("history", args.DataItem.State.GetWorkflow().GetHistory(args.DataItem));
            this.velocityContext.Put("state", args.DataItem.State.GetWorkflowState());
            this.velocityContext.Put("nextState", this.GetNextState(args));
            this.velocityContext.Put("site", Context.Site);
            this.velocityContext.Put("time", DateTime.Now);
            this.velocityContext.Put("previewUrl",string.Format("Http://{0}/?sc_itemid=%7b{1}%7d&sc_mode=preview",Context.Site.HostName,args.DataItem.ID.Guid));
```

The value for previewUrl is not working. Context.Site.HostName is always null.
Is someone know what would be the cause ? Or is there another way to build the link of the article which has to be reviewed / approved or rejected by the content owner ?

Thank you,

Comment: What is Sitecore.Context.Site? Is it the built-in default "website" context? You probably need to add a hostName attribute to it, if so.

Comment: When is this code executing? Is it *after* the SiteResolver pipeline process?

Comment: I took the code from ExtendedEmailAction. A package provided as third party component. As I had an issue with an incorrect assembly version, I have used Reflector and rewrote the class library with my Sitecore.NVelocity.dll version. Inside the code of the ExtendedEmailAction, there was using Context.Site. If I'm using $site.Name inside my email message, I will see that value: 'Shell' which is not correct :) On another post of this forum, I have found an answer where there was using previewurl. Not via Context.Site but via DataAccessSettings.Site.HostName

Comment: The code is executed during the workflow process as it's not really easy to debug that part, I don't know like that if it's after SiteResolver or before :(

Comment: Link on which I m refering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063558/how-do-i-email-the-original-submitter-using-workflow-in-sitecore

Answer (score 0):

If your code is executing in workflow, it's executing in the Shell site context, which will not get you the Site Context or host name you're looking for. You'll need to resolve the site which the item belongs to, and grab the host name from it.

Grab the LinkHelper class from here:
http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/multiple-sites-with-one-authoring-domain-in-sitecore/

Use the LinkHelper to determine the site for the given item. Then grab the HostName from the returned SiteInfo.